# Running awk command in awk script

Tags: awk

I am just looking to run a simple script that runs an awk command inside of the awk script.

```
sample_enrollment.csv file: "EffectiveDate","Status","EmployeeID","ClientID"
```

Below is the Lab4_1.awk

```
 #!/bin/bash

BEGIN{FS=","}

{
awk 'gsub(/EfectiveDate/, "Effective Date")'
}
```

I am running the command from the command line like this

```
awk -f lab4_1.awk sample_enrollment.csv
```

The error that I am getting seems to indicate that the ' ' in the awk gsub command seem to be wrong. I have tried many variations on this awk command with out any luck. I am just asking for this portion, as I will need to add more to the awk script after I get this done

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Why you want to use 2 awk here, if you could tell us the samples input and samples output then may be we could help you within single awk itself. Please post samples in code tags in your post and let me know then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is need for using 2 `awk` commands here as per your shown effort it could be done in single `awk` like as follows too.

```
awk -F, '{gsub(/EfectiveDate/, "Effective Date")} 1'  Input_file
```

As I mentioned in comments too in case you have more requirements you could let us know with samples in code tags in your post and we could help you from there too.

***EDIT:*** As OP mentioned a script is needed so now adding code in a bash script format too.

```
cat script
#!/bin/bash
awk '{gsub("EffectiveDate","Effective Date")} 1' Input_file
......... do my other stuff too here in bash or awk...........
```

Comment: I am just asking for this portion, as I will need to add more to the awk script after I get this done. When this script is finished, I will have many other tasks that will be preformed

Comment: @Ububtunoob, sure, if you could let us know complete requirements then we could help you to do it without calling 2 awks, let us know on same.

Comment: I have updated the original question. I am looking to change the name of EffectiveDate to Effective Date. I can do this from the command line, but want to add it to the script as I will be automating more tasks along with this one

Comment: @Ububtunoob, please check my edit now, you could create a bash script and could do your all requirements there, no need to create awk script for it. Let me know if this helps you now?

Comment: I see. Although, I would need to include the input file (sample_enrollment.csv) inside of the script this way. I was looking to add the command and run it against the file used by the command awk -f lab4_1.awk sample_enrollment.csv. Is there a way that I can use this awk command inside of the script that can be run against the input file provided on the command line?

Comment: Just figured it out  
BEGIN{FS=","}

{
gsub("EffectiveDate","Effective Date",$1)
print $0